# How to get all HTML attributes which start with something (the attribute names, *not* their values!)

Tags: javascript, dom, selector

I would like to get all the elements/nodes in an HTML page which contain attributes that start with something (again, the attribute names start with something, not their values!). For example, TinyMCE has a tendency of adding custom attributes to the elements it saves, like `"mce_style"`, `"mce_href"`, `"mce_bogus"`, etc. I would like to have something like the CSS3 selector for attribute values, `[attr^="mce_"]`, **but not for the values, the attribute names**.

Of course, I can iterate through all DOM nodes and their attributes and check them one by one, but I was wondering whether there is a more efficient way.

Please don't give me TinyMCE-specific answers, I'm pretty sure there's a flag which would prevent TinyMCE for saving these attributes, but the question is generic.

Comment: I have the feeling that you're going to either have to iterate through every element, and look through each of the attributes. Even `document.querySelectorAll()` doesn't have an `attribute-name-begins-with` option. Interesting question.

Comment: I don't know anything about TinyMCE, but if there's some way to identify elements which have *any* such attribute then you can at least narrow your search to a subset first, then look at each attribute of the subset, which would be much faster than looking at the whole dom. That is, is there some attribute that will always be added to one of your targets? If so then look for that first.

Comment: @jamietre Yeah, as far as TinyMCE is concerned, you can assume e.g. that `mce_href` will always be applied to `a` elements, so you can narrow down your search. But as I said in the last sentence, I'm not looking for TinyMCE-specific answers, I would rather have a generic solution, and judging from the answers I got so far, there is no other way than to iterate through all elements and their attributes. Pitty.

Comment: Well, yeah, but it does beg the question of why? I mean, is there any tool that is in widespread use that would put you in such a situation? There's no reason to write code that would create arbitrarily named elements with no other way to identify the node. It's kind of like asking, how can I find every record in a database that has some text, without using a full text index? You don't. You use a full text index.

Comment: Custom (and invalid) attributes in HTML have been (ab)used forever, but this link shows a valid use in HTML 5 and a point for having a fast and generic mechanism that will retrieve these attributes:
http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

If you google "custom html attributes" I'm sure you will find a few more cases.

Comment: 5+ years later and it's custom attributes galore :) Angular for one has all the ng-* attributes, plus attributes in parentheses and brackets! So, I'm still surprised there's no standard selector for this.

Answer (score 6):

[here's a simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H5rVq/2/) to find all elements that contain an attribute starting with `mce_`. might need some refinements.

```
function getMCE() {
    var el, attr, i, j, arr = [],
        reg = new RegExp('^mce_', 'i'),                //case insensitive mce_ pattern
        els = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*'); //get all tags in body

    for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {                 //loop through all tags
        el = els[i]                                    //our current element
        attr = el.attributes;                          //its attributes
        dance: for (j = 0; j < attr.length; j++) {     //loop through all attributes
            if (reg.test(attr[j].name)) {              //if an attribute starts with mce_
                arr.push(el);                          //push to collection
                break dance;                           //break this loop
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(getMCE())​
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the obvious solution, iteration through all elements and their attributes, which is too costly for big DOMs.

Comment: -1 for `break dance` because it will break on the first attribute of an element that matches. An element can have multiple matching attributes. But overall the code above seems to be the only solution at the moment.

Comment: @AsGoodAsItGets you need to `break dance` since you just wanted elements that have attributes prefixed with `mce_`. If it finds an attribute with `mce_` in that element, the script adds the element to the collection and proceeds with another element. No need to parse the rest of the attributes... that is unless you are collecting the attribute names, and not the elements.

Comment: @Joseph You are right Joseph, my apologies. I forgot you are gathering the elements and not the attributes. I would personally refine the script to include the attributes per element, since I plan to remove them afterwards, but that's another story.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**FUNCTIONS**

```
//custom selector expression
$.extend($.expr[':'],{
attr:function(o,i,m){
  var attrs=$.getAttrAll(o),re=m[3],found=false;
  $.each(attrs,function(k,v){
  if(new RegExp(re).test(v)) { return found=true;}
});
return found;
} 
});
// get all atrributes of an element
$.getAttrAll=function(el){
  var rect = [];
  for (var i=0, attrs=el.attributes, len=attrs.length; i<len; i++){
    rect.push(attrs.item(i).nodeName);
  }
  return rect;
};
```

`
**USAGE**

```
// calling custom selector expression :attr(regexp)
$(function(){
  $('body').find(':attr("^mce_")').css({background:'yellow'});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <p mce_style="height:50px" id="x" data-hello="hello">selected</p>
  <div not_mce_bogus="abc">not_mce_bogus</div>
  <div mce_href="http://rahenrangan.com">selected</div>
  <p>othrs</p>
</body>
```

Comment: This is basically a slightly more elegant but I suspect slightly less performant, jQuery-based rewrite of the code posted by Joseph below. It still has to go through each and every element and each and every attribute through the DOM.

What's more, the example usage you mentioned is only considering the immediate children of the body tag, the correct usage would be with `find()` instead of `children()` (although in your simple HTML it will work).

I guess I have to live with the fact that there's no better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

One option, if you don't mind temporarily altering your DOM, is to extract your HTML into a string and search for the attributes via RegExp.  When you find the attributes, you could append a "needle" in the DOM so that you can use jQuery to select the elements.

Here is a working concept (run with console open):

http://jsfiddle.net/skylar/N43Bm/

Code:

```
$.fn.extend({

    findAttributes: function(attribute) {

        var attributeFinder = new RegExp(attribute + '(.+)="', "gi");
        var elementHTML = this.html().replace(attributeFinder, "data-needle='pin' "+attribute+"$1=\"");

        this.html(elementHTML);

        return this.find("[data-needle=pin]").removeAttr('data-needle');
    }

});

console.log($("body").findAttributes('mce_'));
```

Note: my regexp is not great.  You'll have to take better care than I have in this example.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: (I tried putting * instead of `a` tag but it colored all the elements including those who do not have `mce_style` attribute as well)

```
a[mce_style] { color : red; }​
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Tcdmb/

More info : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Ok. This somewhat solves his problem but can not use * or % in `mce_*' to select all the elements having attributes with `mce_` as a prefix.