# Javascript selector engines and built in functions

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I have found the following tutorial on creating a selector engine..
http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2010/04/creating-your-own-selector-engine/

In javascript we have functions like

- getElementById()
- getElementsByTageName()
- getElementsByName()

etc,.....But for the same functionality,in their selector engine,they are doing checks like

```
 this.nodes[i].tagName == nm.toUpperCase()
```

instead of getElementsByTagName.What is the advantage of this approach?...

Also what is the usage of assigning all nodes to a vairiable using

```
 e.getElementsByTagName('*');
```

Comment: We now have `document.querySelector` which can do the hard work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is an inconsistency](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/tagName) when you get the `tagName` property of elements. Some browsers return uppercase and others lowercase. To normalize the output of the value, you have to do one or the other before continuing further operation.

As for `e.getElementsByTagName('*');`, [i recently answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10314363/575527) where the OP wants to find ALL elements containing an attribute *name* which has a prefix `mce_`. The only way to get such elements is to get all elements in the DOM, and inspect their attribute names.

There is also a good application of this `getElementsByTagName('*')` and that is determining the direct child of an element. For instance, in a very deep DOM. If I were to find certain parent elements based on an attribute and get it's children, normally you would do a recursive search from body downwards to find the parent. This would take a lot of recursive operations. Afterwards, you determine their children.

Another way to do it is to get all tags, determine their parent node, and if they have the parent with the attribute, they are the direct child. This method requires no recursion, only `getElementsByTagName('*')` and a loop through the `nodeList` that was returned.

Answer (score 1):

`this.nodes[i].tagName == nm.toUpperCase()` is part of a method to filter the list of nodes by tag name.... so nothing to do with 'getting elements by their tag name'

the last point is not a real question.. you want to know reasons for "why would you select all nodes"? well you are writing a sector engine....

Answer (score 1):

The following line

```
this.nodes[i].tagName == nm.toUpperCase()
```

Is within the function `ofTag`. It's filtering a set of nodes looking for  nodes with the given name.

The next line

```
e.getElementsByTagName('*');
```

Retrieves all the children/descendants under a node so you can later filter it like the following

```
new DOMNodes(Selector.getAll(document)).ofTag('p').hasClass('note');
```