# Getting all HTML elements in the DOM where an attribute name starts with some-string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've stumbled upon a tricky one, that I haven't been able to find any references to (except one here on Stackoverflow, that was written quite inefficiently in Plain Old Javascript - where I would like it written in jQuery).

**Problem**

I need to retrieve all child-elements where the **attribute-name** (note: **not** the *attribute-value*) starts with a given string.

So if I have:

```
<a data-prefix-age="22">22</a>
<a data-prefix-weight="82">82</a>
<a href="#">meh</a>
```

My query would return a collection of two elements, which would be the first two with the **data-prefix-**-prefix

Any ideas on how to write up this query?

I was going for something like:

```
$(document).find("[data-prefix-*]")
```

But of course that is not valid

Hopefully one of you has a more keen eye on how to resolve this.

**Solution**

(See accepted code example below)

There is *apparently* **no direct way to query on partial attribute names**. What you should do instead (this is just one possible solution) is

1. select the smallest possible collection of elements you can
2. iterate over them
3. and then for each element iterate over the attributes of the element
4. When you find a hit, add it to a collection
5. then leave the loop and move on to the next element to be checked.

You should end up with an array containing the elements you need.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Which was the solution you found?

Comment: This one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313312/how-to-get-all-html-attributes-which-start-with-something-the-attribute-names - I tried the jQuery example, but I don't get the right results. I also found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543733/jquery-attribute-name-contains which I'm testing right now.

Comment: here http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ I can't see any suitable selector for the function find(). You may just enum all attributes from each child element recursively, select matching ones and return?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a solution in "Plain Old Javascript"

Comment: @sachleen: I don't disagree - I simply prefer keeping to the jQuery paradigm, whenever possible. Generally because I get less surprises, cleaner code and generally better performance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will do the trick -

```
    // retrieve all elements within the `#form_id` container
    var $formElements = $("form#form_id > *");

    var selectedElements = [];
    // iterate over each element
    $formElements.each(function(index,elem){
        // store the JavaScript "attributes" property
        var elementAttr = $(this)[0].attributes;
        // iterate over each attribute
        $(elementAttr).each(function(attIndex,attr){
            // check the "nodeName" for the data prefix
            if (attr.nodeName.search('data-.*') !== -1){
               // we have found a matching element!
               if (selectedElements.length < 2){
                 selectedElements.push(elem);
                 break;
               }else{
                 if (selectedElements.length == 2){
                   break(2);
                 }
               }
            }
        });
    });
```

`selectedElements` will now hold the first two matching elements.

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLbpn/6/)

Comment: if I were to run this again all elements in a <form>-tag, how would that look ? can you refactor it to show that ?

Comment: So far I am able to get the elements I need so it seems this is pretty close to what I am looking for. Thanks alot!

Comment: A small fix to the above code, shouldn't you instead do:             if (attr.nodeName.search('data-.*') !== -1) {            selectedElements.push(elem); return false; } to exit the ".each" after a find and push ?

Comment: Indeed - that is a great point @cod!  I'll edit that in as well - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquerys filter() method to have a selections elements being processed by a function. Inside that function you are free to do whatever you want to.

So start with selecting *all* elements inside the dom tree and filter out everything you dislike. Not especially fast, but working.