# JQuery Selector - Select with *

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this html code:

```
<div data-r-foo="mfoo" data-r-bar="mbar"></div>
<div data-r-zoo="mfso"></div>
<div data-r-too="too" data-r-foo="mfoo"></div>
```

now I want to select all elements with `data-r*` and the elements they have multiple `data-r*` like first element and last element must be selected once.
I have tried this but my IDE shows a syntax error

```
$('[data-r*]');
```

Comment: Anybody know the answer for this question I am willing to know the answer

Comment: @RodrigoDela It's not my purpose, I want to select every nodes with `data-r*` attrib

Comment: And here's another duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657398/jquery-how-to-select-value-by-attribute-name-starts-with And one more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313312/how-to-get-all-html-attributes-which-start-with-something-the-attribute-names

Comment: Why is this being reopened when it's a clear duplicate?

Comment: @tymeJV: He wanted a prefix match of the name. That'll only give an exact match.